# Filter views for a pivot table

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, microsoft-teams

I have an excel spreadsheet containing a pivot table on one tab. If I share this via teams link with multiple people and autosave is on, is there a way to have a filter view on this table?

I have attempted to add a custom view but that is the only option I can see. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.